# unexpected excel crash at saving

Tags: excel, vba

Anyone could tell me why excel crashes at line

```
Workbooks(strFichero).Save 'Here
     'Cierro libro, guardando
    Do Until Workbooks(strFichero).Saved
        Workbooks(strFichero).Save
    Loop

    Workbooks(strFichero).Close
```

[image]

Comment: Why would you loop to save? Just `Save`.

Comment: I try just save on first line (i tried to modify that :) ), but same result

Error appears also in Workbooks(strFichero).Save 'Here

Comment: Are you sure there an open workbook named like `strFichero` variable exist?

Answer (score 1):

You are not giving it enough time to save. Also you do not need a loop like @BigBen mentioned. Simply use `Workbooks(strFichero).Save`.

You need to give time after the save command so that excel can save. Add `DoEvents` before `Workbooks(strFichero).Close` and it will be ok.

For example

```
Workbooks(strFichero).Save
DoEvents
Workbooks(strFichero).Close
```

**Alternatively** you can also use this one liner

```
Workbooks(strFichero).Close (True)
'OR
Workbooks(strFichero).Close SaveChanges:=True
```

You can use the `SaveChanges` parameter of [Workbook.Close method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.close)

```
expression.Close (SaveChanges, FileName, RouteWorkbook)
```

Comment: Hi Siddharth.
Finally, the code was well written. The error was from EXCEL itself.
I reinstalled and the error disappeared

Comment: Great! But do incorporate the suggestions that I gave above.

Comment: I'm sure!
Your advices are always very useful